# Python iterator returning unwanted 'None'

Tags: python, iterator

Why is my iterator returning extra 'None' in the output.  For the parameters/example below, I am getting `[None,4,None]` instead of the desired `[4]`  Can anyone explain why I am getting the extra None and how I can fix it?  The print out 'returning' only appears once so I am assuming only one item should be appended to the returning calling function.

code:

```
class Prizes(object):
    def __init__(self,purchase,n,d):
        self.purchase = purchase
        self.length = len(purchase)
        self.i = n-1
        self.n = n
        self.d = d

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.i < self.length:
            old = self.i
            self.i += self.n
            if (self.purchase[old])%(self.d) == 0:
                print("returning")
                return old+1
        else:
            raise StopIteration

def superPrize(purchases, n, d):
    return list(Prizes(purchases, n, d))

purchases = [12, 43, 13, 465, 1, 13]
n = 2
d = 3
print(superPrize(purchases, n, d))
```

Output:

```
returning
[None, 4, None]
```

Comment: What does `__next__` return if `self.purchase[old] % self.d != 0`?

Comment: @user, you could also simplify your code until you zero in on the source of the problem; your modulo algorithm is not what your question is about.

Comment: You should set `self.i = self.n-1` in `def __iter__(self)` so that your iterator re-sets whenever you want to iterate again

Comment: @Aaron - that's an interesting point, but in that case OP should return a different object that does the iteration instead. Consider a file object that does not reset is iterator every time you call `iter()`. That means that future iterators keep consuming from the current file position instead of rewinding. So, in this example, OP should not reset the iterator so that an `iter()` call doesn't break the current iteration.

Comment: This was a good question and a non-obvious bug. Lets give this guy some up-votes to repair his reputation.

Comment: @tdelaney that's a good point. I saw it as something that could be easily overlooked and a potential source of frustration "why did it work the first time but then not again until I restarted my interactive shell"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As people in the comments have pointed out, your line `if (self.purchase[old])%(self.d) == 0:` leads to the function returning without any return value. If there is no return value supplied `None` is implied. You need some way of continuing through your list to the next available value that passes this test before returning or raising `StopIteration`. One easy way of doing this is simply to add an extra `else` clause to call `self.__next__()` again if the test fails.

```
def __next__(self):
        if self.i < self.length:
            old = self.i
            self.i += self.n
            if (self.purchase[old])%(self.d) == 0:
                print("returning")
                return old+1
            else:
                return self.__next__()
        else:
            raise StopIteration
```

Comment: Yea, it didnt occur to me that whenever my if statement is not met, it returns a None.  This was explained by @tdelaney as well.  As for your solution, its definitely a nice alternative.  Thanks

Comment: @user1179317 he beat me to the punch by a minute or two, but credit really goes to vaultah.

Comment: This is risky because python has a maxumum recursion limit. On my machine this would raise an exception if self.d is about 1000. If you use recursion, you need some mechanism to stop that from happening.

Comment: @tdelaney Very true. Some time I'll have a mind to write in tail call optimization and propose as a PEP. It's something I wish python had all the time...

Answer (score 2):

Functions return `None` if you don't have an explicit `return` statement. That's what happens in `__next__` when `if (self.purchase[old])%(self.d) == 0:` isn't true. You want to stay in your `__next__` until it has a value to return.

```
class Prizes(object):
    def __init__(self,purchase,n,d):
        self.purchase = purchase
        self.length = len(purchase)
        self.i = n-1
        self.n = n
        self.d = d

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        while self.i < self.length:
            old = self.i
            self.i += self.n
            if (self.purchase[old])%(self.d) == 0:
                return old+1
        raise StopIteration

def superPrize(purchases, n, d):
    return list(Prizes(purchases, n, d))

purchases = [12, 43, 13, 465, 1, 13]
n = 2
d = 3
print(superPrize(purchases, n, d))
```